# Set Header in htacces based on environment variable

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to set HTST Header in .htaccess based on kind of request (https or http). I tried to modify this piece of code, which sets header "max-age=300" to image files by checking E variable:

```
RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpg) - [E=image:1]
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=300" env=image
```

This way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=STRICT_ENV:1]
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;" env=STRICT_ENV
```

But seems that STRICT_ENV variable is not set at all.

Comment: My first guess would be that you might need to use the `PT` flag, because you rewrite to `-`. I can't test that right now though. However, it does not make much sense to me to omit the HTST header from HTTP connections. You either want all your connections to be https, or you don't.

Comment: The goal was to serve iframes with http content within certain pages on website, which is impossible in https, it triggers "Mixed content" error

Answer (score 0):

Give this header a try:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" env=HTTPS
```